# PaperSize cannot be changed unless the Kind property is set to Custom

Tags: c#, printers, epson

Hi I am working on a project where I need to set the printer setting for setting custom height and width for printer. I am using EPSON LW-900P printer for sticker printing.

I am trying to set the height property of printer setting object but it's throwing an error like "PaperSize cannot be changed unless the Kind property is set to Custom." I know we can not set the property if Kind property is not set as a custom, but in my case papersize is set as custom however I am not able to set the height property.

Please see the below image for reference
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance if someone can me guide to resolve this issue.

Comment: Set the height via the PaperSize() ctor?

Comment: already tried with PaperSize ctor as well with no luck

Comment: Given the name, this looks like a predefined custom paper size provided by the printer driver.  Have a look-see at the printer properties in Control Panel.  Whether you can change such a predefined size is up to the printer driver.  Usually it says no!  Seems you are trying to create your own custom paper size but there is no obvious call to PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Add(ps) to actually add the new size.